# How to stop unwanted Nvidia Shield TV wake up?

Tags: standby, android-tv, nvidia-shield

My Nvidia Shield TV wake up from standby mode undesirably (and wake up my tv).

So my first question: Is it possible to get a log to see what awakens it?

On a more empirical approach, I have noticed two behaviors somewhat contradictory and strange:

- If I connect a wired gamepad, the shield tv wakes up more often.
- Without internet access (but with a local network) the shield tv doesn't wake up

So, my other question is: what can I do to stop these wake up?

(My shield tv is rooted and I have sideloaded some apps, maybe it's related but I prefer to avoid a reset...)

Thank you.

Comment: Would disconnecting the wifi on standy/screen off and reconnecting it on screen on solve your issue? If so you can try setting up a conditional task on Tasker.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try when I have time... But do you know if tasker can control wired connection?

Answer (score 1):

1. try to shake your gamepad slightly to see if this action will trigger the wake up of you tv.
2. install the [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) on you Nvidia Shield TV, which will show you the wake up relation, and also you can disable the wake up.
3. alternatively, if you found out the apps that wake up your tv, you can use [ice box](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catchingnow.icebox) to freeze the apps.